# How to make refreshrate stay saved in 14.04?

Tags: graphics, video

Using Ubuntu with XBMC I need to run Ubuntu with a refreshrate of 50Hz. to avoid judder watching european TV.

Can anybody help ? 
Using xrandr I can change it to 1920x1080, 50 Hz. but after reboot it falls back to 60Hz.

Chip-set: BayTrail M with Intel HD-Graphics

Best regards

Comment: a not so polite way to let a command execute every time I start my machine is to write it in `/etc/rc.local` cheers